# Call function over every column sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, dynamicquery

let's say I have a table with a lot of columns and I want to call same function on every of them (for example `MAX`). Is it possible without listing all columns?
That is instead of

```
Select max(col1), max(col2), max(col3)
from table1
```

write

```
Select max(col)
for col in table1.columns
from table1
```

Comment: There is no such T-SQL syntax. You'll need to use dynamic SQL to generate and execute the desired query if you need to go there.

Comment: Also note that you can't call MAX/MIN on all data types, notable exclusions include [BIT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/min-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#arguments)

Comment: You will need to generate a suitable query by dynamically building it from querying `sys.columns` and `sys.types`

Comment: "a table with a lot of columns" mistake #1. Most tables should be relatively narrow. If your table is wide you should think carefully about whether your database design is correct and conforming to Normal Forms.

Comment: Just echoing the dynamic SQL if you don't know the table or columns ahead of time. If all you want to do is save typing, then a utility like NimbleText will let you just paste in a list of column names (which you just query from INFORMATION_SCHEMA_COLUMNS), and it can produce a SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, or whatever you need that affects all those columns. Google NimbleText and give it a try, if that's all you're after.

Answer (score 0):

There is no out of the box function to do that but since you have dynamic function tagged I assume that you want an example of dynamic code as well.

```
DECLARE @TableName VARCHAR(50) = 'put the table name here'
DECLARE @SqlCmd VARCHAR(MAX) = ''

SELECT @SqlCmd = @SqlCmd + ',MAX(' + QUOTENAME(c.name) + ') as ' + QUOTENAME(c.name)
        -- optional line break
        +CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)
FROM sys.columns c
INNER JOIN sys.tables t ON  c.object_id = t.object_id
WHERE t.name = @TableName
ORDER BY c.column_id

SET @SqlCmd = 'SELECT ' + STUFF(@SqlCmd,1,1,'') + ' FROM ' + QUOTENAME (@TableName)

--PRINT @SqlCmd
--SELECT @SqlCmd
EXEC (@SqlCmd)
```

Answer (score 0):

Execute the dynamic query using `sp_executesql`.

```
DECLARE @sqlQuery NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'SELECT';

SELECT @sqlQuery = @sqlQuery + ' MAX(' + QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) + ') AS ' + QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) + ','
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'table1';

SET @sqlQuery = LEFT(@sqlQuery, LEN(@sqlQuery) - 1) + ' FROM table1';

EXEC sp_executesql @sqlQuery;
```

Hope it's work